# Using itemId to fetch component Extjs

Tags: extjs

I had a problem with tab rendering. The contents of the tabs used to get mixed up as i used the same component on all the tabs and the component had sub-components with id. As the id would appear same on all panels, the components used to get mixed up. I am now using itemId instead of id and the tabs are getting rendered properly. 
Now I am facing another problem. Initially I used Ext.getCmp(id) to fetch components in the controller. Now that ids are replaced by itemId, I am using the following:
`Ext.getCmp(id).getComponent(itemId);`

There is a deep nesting of components in the view and all the intermediate components have itemId. With the above statement, as I go on to fetch deeper components, the statements keeps extending like:

```
Ext.getCmp(id).getComponent(itemId1).getComponent(itemId2).getComponent(....;
```

Am I using the statement correctly? Is there a better shorthand method to achieve the purpose?

Please advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the Ext.ComponentQuery.query(..) or down() or up() to get the component you are referring to.

If you want to get a component(say a button) within a certain component(say within a container) ,you can use

```
 var button = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('button[type=messageButton]', this);
```

In the above 'this' refers to the container scope.

Or you can use

```
var button = this.query('button[type=messageButton]');
```

In the above also 'this' refers to the container scope.

Hope this helps you ..

Comment: Thank you Sreek521! This is what i needed. I donot even have to trace down the component through its complete path...

Answer (score 11):

Basically you using it the right way because a `itemId` is only unique at component level (at least it has to). But as you might see this will get sort of ugly, therefore I strictly recommend you to use `Ext.ComponentQuery` or one of it's implementations `up()` and `down()` which are both available for most components. Where `Ext.ComponentQuery` will per default look through the all instantiated components `up()` and `down()` will start at the component from which they are executed, only walking through the existing component tree. Also `up()` and `down()` always returns the first match where `Ext.ComponentQuery` always present you a array.

Both accepting the same query string which can be written in various ways (here I recommend you to read the [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery))

Here is a example for:

```js
Ext.getCmp(íd).getComponent(itemId1).getComponent(itemId2)
```

expecting that you are using panels (it can be any component)

```js
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('panel[id=yourId]>panel[itemId=yourId]>panel[itemId=yourId]');
```

lets say you are using MVC and therefore all your components are custom (have own xtypes). So if you know, that you have only one instance of 'yourcustompanel' with this `itemId` you may the simply call:

```js
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('yourcustompanel[itemId=yourId]') // note you get always a array
```